# Regex Pattern Matching for Ping result

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract a value out of a ping but can't seem to work out how to get the value after a certain number of "/".

The value in bold is what I'm trying to get -

```
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.347/2.178/3.199/0.769 ms
```

I've tried:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/(.*?)/");
```

But that returns everything between a "/" and I dont want to loop through it until i hit the 2nd numerical value.

Could someone help me with the pattern?

Comment: Please provide right input, I don't see any bold in your input.

Answer (score 1):

> bluebrigade23 said -But that returns everything between a "/" and I dont want to loop
>   through it until i hit the 2nd numerical value.

If you know second numerical value is what you require then why are you using a regular expression,while you could simply split the strings which is a more portable way

```
    String[] no = "1.347/2.178/3.199/0.769 ms".split("/");
    System.out.println(no[1]);
```

This will produce 2.178 as an output which is more simpler and efficient

Comment: Because i would be going through something a result that is more like:

    64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=59 time=24.6 ms


    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.347/2.178/3.199/0.769 ms

Which is one string, would the split work for that too?

Comment: @bluebrigade23 you can still use this approach by splitting on a substring

line.substring(line.lastIndexOf("="), line.length()).split("/")

Comment: @bluebrigade23 yet more simpler approach
  String[] words = line.split("rtt min/avg/max/mdev = ");
               where line is your string words[1] will give the string "1.347/2.178/3.199/0.769 ms" then you could follow my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("/([0-9]*[.][0-9]+)/");
String line = "rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.347/2.178/3.199/0.769 ms";
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(line);
if(matcher.find()) {
    String group = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(group);
}
```

**Outputs**

> 2.178

Comment: Trying to understand the pattern, does that just grab anything the vale between the first couple of "/"?

Comment: `[0-9]*[.][0-9]+` searches for anything like a decimal (i.e. 2.178 or .178) and the surrounding parentheses make it a group.
The beginning and ending `/` force it to be inside `/.../`